# partial view loaded by Ajax do not render code after @RenderBody

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application developped in C# / MVC4.

It has a top menu and bottom menu.

A partial view is loaded in the main view when I click on a link (banana or apple) using ajax:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Connection", "Details", "SourceConfiguration", new { id = "4505F2DE-91A2-496B-9BCB-BD1D3C2C3FB1" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
```

When the link is clicked, it should also modify the layout in order to display different top and bottom menus: (similar to Windows Azure bottom menu which display contextual action depending on where you are).

How I can I achieve that? (see below for what has been tested).

[image: Architecture]

What has been tried so far:
The default _layout.cshtml contains

```
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("Bottom", false)
```

the home/index.cshtml contains this code:

```
@section Bottom 
{
the code to create the bottom menu 
  [...]
}
```

=> This is correctly rendered.

Here comes the problem:
each page in the views contain the Bottom section.
The bottom section is not displayed in pages called by partial view (ex: views/apple/index.cshtml).

What's the best way when I click on Apple to display the partial view and to display a specific top and bottom bar?

Comment: if you just have buttons or links in the bottom and top I would just hide or show those buttons using jquery.  If you have more content than that you can load a separate partial view for that section

Comment: Can you consider creating a similar layout as your main layout but with extra tabs as you want. and you can call this layout when ever you require

Comment: How can my link update 3 partial views or layout?Because if I follow you, I should create 3 partial views, one for the top, bottom bar and one for the current partial view. Today, it's an ajax shortcut: @Ajax.ActionLink("Connection", "Details", "SourceConfiguration", new { id = "4505F2DE-91A2-496B-9BCB-BD1D3C2C3FB1" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })

Comment: @reddy: I've tried this: _layout2.cshtml which is a clone of _layout.Cshtml. Everything works except the bottom bar which is not displayed as if after @RenderBody() nothing is rendered anymore

Comment: Try keeping the bottom tabs syntax in <footer></footer> then it willbe rendered after  @RenderBody()

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

in HomeController:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult MenuLayout(string name)
{
    return PartialView("_MenuLayout", null);            
}
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult MenuBottomLayout(string name)
{
     return PartialView("_MenuBottomLayout", null);            
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="navcontainer">
</div>   

<div class="">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<div class="navcontainerbottom">
</div>
```

And javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var menuLoaded = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
if($('.navcontainer')[0].innerHTML.trim() == "")
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/MenuLayout")",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response, status, xhr)
                        {
                            var nvContainer = $('.navcontainer');
                            nvContainer.html(response);
                            menuLoaded = true;
                        },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                            var nvContainer = $('.navcontainer');
                        nvContainer.html(errorThrown);
                    }
            });
}
if($('.navcontainerbottom')[0].innerHTML.trim() == "")
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/MenuBottomLayout")",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response, status, xhr)
                        {
                            var nvContainer = $('.navcontainerbottom');
                            nvContainer.html(response);
                            menuLoaded = true;
                        },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                            var nvContainer = $('.navcontainerbottom');
                        nvContainer.html(errorThrown);
                    }
            });
   }
});
</script>
```

And finally _MenuLayout.cshtml and MenuBottomLayout.cshtml contain the code that create the top and bottom menu.